# $_GET value from HTACCESS url

Tags: php, .htaccess

Goes without saying, I know completely nothing about HTACCESS. I'm coding a referral system in PHP, and it all works, although it stops working when I use HTACCESS to make the URLs pretty. Example:

From

```
http://localhost/ref.php?referral=1
```

To

```
http://localhost/ref/1
```

Now the code works and all, it just stops working when I use HTACCESS, I remember reading from somewhere, if I'm not wrong, that you can't use the _GET function from a URL which has passed through HTACCESS? None the less, I've tried this HTACCESS rule, but it doesn't seem to work.. It redirects, as per the code it told to do when it drops the cookie, but it's not actually dropping the cookie when I use the shortened URL.

```
RewriteRule ^ref/([^/]+)(|/)$ /ref.php?referral=$1
```

The code of the script, if it helps understand the issue..

```
    if (isset($_GET['referral']))
{
    $value = $_GET['referral']; // Let's set the cookie value
    // Drop the cookie, let it expire in an hour. 
    setcookie("HHRefCookie", $value, time()+3600);
    // Redir them to register page
    header("Location: " . WWW . "/register");
}
```

From my understanding, this should be working? Should it not. Feedback would be appreciated. And guidance towards the right direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "_it just stops working_" ? Do you have an error ?

Comment: No. It redirects to the location set within the code. It's not dropping the cookie, so it musn't be reading the variable.

Comment: _“I remember reading from somewhere, if I'm not wrong, that you can't use the _GET function from a URL which has passed through HTACCESS?”_ – that is wrong; of course you can access a query string parameter via $_GET in PHP – where that parameter came from, original request or rewritten one, does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the status code returned by the server? I can't see how the rewrite rule you've provided would match the URL schema you are using (i.e. I'd expect the server to return a 404).

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^/ref/(.*)$ /ref.php?referral=$1 [L]
```

(and if this is Apache 2.4 then use [END] rather than [L])

Comment: No errors, still redirects. The rule provided still doesn't work, it's going wrong somewhere. It's still not grabbing the referral ID.. When I remove the redirection URL, and echo the cookie, it drops the cookie, but when I redirect it to the register page (where it should be able to read the cookie) the cookie doesn't exist.

Comment: "it still redirects" - then given the code you've provided the rewrite rule working exactly as it should (however I have NO IDEA HOW IT DID THAT when your original rewrite rule was wrong). Dropping a cookie in a redirect is a really bad idea - I would expect that to fail depending on the browser you are using - the behaviour is undefined by the spec.